# SVG mouseover behavior lost when trying to load it from external resource into html

Tags: svg

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq44G/)

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="20"
   height="20">
    <path fill="#a00"
       fill-opacity="1"
       stroke="none"
    d="M 0,0 L 17,9 L 0,18 L 6,9 Z"
       transform="rotate(180 8.5 9)"
       onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('fill', '#cc0');"
       onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('fill','#a00');"/>
</svg>
```

it displays an arrow which changes color as you hover over it.

If i save above code in a svg file, then try to include it in a page via javascript like below:

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74728667/left_arrow.svg";
div.appendChild(img);
```

i can see the arrow but the hover behavior is lost - example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/92cNV/). its understandable as the svg has been reduced to an `img`. My question is what can i do so that i don't lose the hover behavior? note i am not interested in getting the hover behavior via css since i don't like having the code in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the SVG via an `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag instead. Both allow interactivity and scripting, neither of which are allowed by the `<img>` tag.